# Site Navigation "Open Link in New Window" does not work

Tags: 2013, navigation, team-sites

I have added the following setting inside my sub site navigation to show all the available users inside a People group:-

[image]

but currently when i click on the link , it will not open in a new window ,, can anyone adivce on this please?

Thanks

Comment: Are you only using "/_layouts/15/blablabla"? Try to use the full path instead.

Comment: ok even if i specify the full path ,,, it will be automatically trimmed...

Comment: I see. Seems like the criminal was the minimal download strategy.. to often. :)

Comment: @user19952 sharepoint is making me loses my mind ,, lot of bugs ......

Comment: Haha, yepp! Losing more hair everyday and major heartaches from day to day!

Answer (score 1):

A PM in my company expressed that a client’s subsites (that were based on the team site template) were not respecting the navigation setting (the structured navigation tool) to open links in a new window. All the setting does is add a target=”_blank” to the link. Here is what the setting looks like (from Site Settings – Navigation):

[image]

From what I can tell, other site templates do not have this issue. In team sites, the following JS function is adding to the div above the global and local navigation, and it causes the target to be ignored:

```
onclick="return AjaxNavigate$OnClickHook(event, this);"
```

In the init.js you can see where it’s pointing to, but ultimately I can’t tell what the purpose of this is. All it seems to do is extend the URL to use hashes. Here’s an example of the type of URL it generates when clicking on a document library.

http://server/teamsite/_layouts/15/start.aspx#//teamsite/Meetings/Forms/AllItems.aspx

So it turns out this feature is part of the 2013 minimal download strategy enabled by default on team sites. When this feature is disabled the open in new window functionality is restored. To me, this is still a bug because the MDS should still honor the navigation functionality (or at least remove the option when the feature is enabled).

So, what about a fix? For that, simply remove the onclick event (which they shouldn’t be doing anyway, cf. unobtrustive JavaScript) using client-side scripting. Here’s an example with jQuery (if you have a custom master page make sure the library is referenced, or you could add a module if you don’t have a master page):

```
$("div[id*='V4QuickLaunchMenu'], div[id*='TopNavigationMenu']").removeAttr("onclick")
```

Comment: ok now i disable the "minimal download strategy " and links  will open in new tab !!! not sure if i need to keep it disabled or to look for another fix?

Comment: @Manish, it is better if you refrence the article from where you copy this.

Comment: credits -- http://www.siolon.com/blog/sharepoint-2013-site-navigation-does-not-open-in-new-window/